# PHP & MySQL & forms -- flexible search? (ex: X ingredients can make Y recipes)

Tags: php, mysql, search, dynamic

I'm just getting started with PHP/MySQL, so please forgive the rather simplistic question:

As a practice example, I want to create a small dbase of recipes. Each recipe has X different ingredients. The table is simple enough I think - each row represents a recipe and each column after the first(primary key) is an ingredient with a TRUE/FALSE value (needs/doesn't need).

But how do I craft a checkbox-based form that can search that table such that if I check 5 different ingredients (carrots, pork, rice, butter, potatoes) the query will return every recipe that I can make with only those 5 ingredients?

So a recipe that uses those 5 and something else WOULD NOT be returned.
But a recipe that uses only 4 of those 5 WOULD be returned.

With my limited knowledge, the query string I'm envisioning seems crammed with IFs and awfully unwieldy... and that's only for a few ingredients, what if I had over a hundred? Yikes.

Answer (score 5):

You should design your table differently:

- Recipes - ID,Name
- Ingredients - ID, name
- RecipesIngredients - recipeID, ingredientID,amount

  ```
  Recipes
  ID name
  1 scalloped potato
  2 cheesy carrots
  3 saucy potato

  Ingredients
  ID name
  1 potato
  2 sauce
  3 cheese
  4 carrots

  RecipesIngredients
  recipesID ingredientID    amount
  1          1               5 lbs
  1          2               2 cups
  1          3               1 cup
  2          3               1/2 cup
  2          4               2 whole
  3          2               a smidge
  3          1               1 whole red
  ```

To get all recipes that have cheese and potato:

```
SELECT * from recipes r 
INNER JOIN RecipesIngredients ri on r.id=ri.recipeID
INNER JOIN Ingredients i on i.id = ri.ingredientID
WHERE i.name in ('cheese','potato')
```

Comment: Just for the record, if you're curious, this is called an EAV database model. It stands for Entity-Attribute-Value. The entity in this case is the Recipe, the Attribute is the Ingredient, and the Value is the Amount.

The harder part comes in designing the query to get the data out of the table the way you want it...  I believe Byron's example will return some recipes which you don't want.